# Software/Framework Recommendations

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, uv4l, webrtc

I'm prototyping a device using a raspberry pi 3b+. Here are some of the requirements I'm hoping to fulfill.

*When I say "device" I'm referring to the raspberry pi.

[image: network diagram]

**Device Requirements**

- Stream device microphone audio input over network

  - utilize echo cancellation
  - simultaneously stream while playing local audio on device
- Control the output of audio files on local device

  - **Controls:** choose from static list of files, play, pause, volume, etc
- Output audio from remote sources over network, which would temporarily pause any other output
- no internet connection required
- user can connect to multiple devices
- device can handle multiple users connected to it

Here is a list of frameworks I am considering in no particular order:

- PulseAudio
- uv4l
- rest api
- web sockets (Mqtt, WebRTC)
- webrtc
- RTSP

WebRTC seems like a good solution for the bi-directional audio streaming, but I can't determine if whatever I use for that will cooperate with the device's ability to playback local audio files. If not, I could probably find some minimal audio library controller api that I could tap in to.

Comment: Welcome -- but open ended and opinion based discussion style questions such as this one do not work with our format.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works, and read *["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*.  Basically, specific questions about using a specific framework, or about what to use to accomplish *a specific task in a specific context* (as opposed to brainstorming an entire project) are fine....

Comment: ...Note though that general programming questions involving frameworks that have a more general application than the Pi belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) .

Comment: I can't even post the image over on the parent site due to lack of reputation. I don't k now how to make my question for specific, so I guess I'm just SOL.

Comment: @ahamill, Ah, let me see.  Perhaps you can ask more specific, shorter, Rpi related questions one by one, like this: "I would like to prototype an audio streaming network using a couple of Rpi3B+s, perhaps using PauseAudio. Any pointers or experiences to share would be much appreciated, blah, blah, blah, ..." LOL.

Comment: Ahamill, in all seriousness: If you find it impossible to drill down on this you should not be undertaking the project.  I took it from the question that you had some previous experience in system / software and electronics design.  If not, you are starting off too ambitiously and need to knuckle down and learn the basics first.